# Compilation and linking of modules independent of ordering in file

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran

I have a set of modules for a `Main` fortran program.
The inheritance order is:

`user_input` > `really_long_module` > `useful_module` > `Main`

where `user_input` is independent and does not inherit from any other modules.

For purposes of improved usability I would like to move `really_long_module` to the end of the file because it is rarely updated and is very long. While `useful_module` is where the user will frequently make changes, so it feels reasonable that this should be close to the beginning of the file.

I have been reading about `make` files and how they can be used to indicate dependencies. However, I have not been able to find any `make` examples that describe the module inter-dependencies that exist within a single file.

My question: is it possible within a single fortran file, to write the modules in an order that is independent of their dependencies and use a `make` file to describe the dependencies during compilation?

MWE:

```
module user_input
  integer, PARAMETER :: N = 2

end module user_input


module really_long_module
    use user_input, only: N
    implicit none

        real :: test_number = N

end module really_long_module


module useful_module
  use user_input
  use really_long_module
  SAVE

  real :: useful_output

END MODULE useful_module


PROGRAM Main
  use user_input
  use really_long_module
  use useful_module

    useful_output = 2 * N

    print*, useful_output

END PROGRAM Main

! ### Would like to put really_long_module at the end of file
! module really_long_module
!     use user_input, only: N
!     implicit none
!
!       real :: test_number = 0.5
!
! end module really_long_module
```

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. Why not place (each?) module in a separate file?

Comment: To expand on @albert 's comment Makefiles are usually used to describe the dependencies between different files - so if you place each module in a separate file it looks like you have something which fits this model very well. You can't do it if everything is in one file if for no other reason than the compiler always considers a whole file, not just part of it.

Comment: @albert I have the opinion that for this application, having everything in one file is simpler rather than having every module in a separate file.

Comment: @IanBush Thank you - the compiler always considers the whole file, not just a segment. That is helpful (and perhaps should have been obvious)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing would prevent a compiler to work with modules appearing in a file in arbitrary order. However, it is usual that compilers work sequentially when analyzing a source file and require that all modules referred by a program unit would have been processed before.

Notice that the standard does not put any restriction on the program units order but, at least in the 2003 draft ISO/IEC FCD 1539-1:2004(E) it was recognizing the existing practice by stating that

> This standard places no ordering requirement on the program units that constitute a program, but
> because the public portions of a module are required to be available by the time a module reference
> is processed, a processor may require a particular order of processing of the program units.